# Find each different cells value in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Sorry if this have been ask before. I don't really know what to look for. I have an excel sheet where on column A I have something that looks like this

```
       A
________________  
1 |  Banana
2 |  Banana
3 |  Banana
4 |  Banana
5 |
6 |  Potato
7 |  Potato
8 |  Potato
9 |  Potato
10|
11|  Noodles
12|  Noodles
13|  Noodles
14|  Noodles
```

But I want to change it to

```
       H
________________  
1 |  Banana
2 |  Potato
3 |  Noodles
```

I know how to find a word in a column but I don't know how to find all the different ones. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1:A12").Copy Range("H1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$H$1:$H$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

***EDIT#1:***

To get rid of the spaces, use this instead:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1:A12").Copy Range("H1")
    Range("$H$1:$H$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("$H$1:$H$12").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but the example I had in my question is not exactly what I have in my sheet. I updated my question now to show you. There is a space between every product and I don't want the space to be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Data" tab, choose "Remove Duplicates".

Comment: This has to be done with vba since this is only one step in my macro and this also has to be run on multiple sheets

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, hitting that very same "remove duplicates" button and then seeing what code it gives you?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA method RemoveDuplicates operates on a Range and does the same thing as the menu option.

[Microsoft MSDN Reference for Excel 2010 RemoveDuplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823(v=office.14).aspx)